# Gradle try to download from wrong repository

Tags: android, maven, gradle, artifactory

My Android APP is pointing to my internal Artifactory only. But build break when it tries to download play-services-base from jcenter.bintray

The funny thing is that I never reference jcenter in my build.gradle either in my project level or module/app level.

play-services-base is available in my jfrog.

I tried to run ./gradlew tasks first to force gradle to download dependencies before building.

At my project level build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"

    ...

    repositories {
        maven {
            url "${rootDir}/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'http://fakeurl/from_artifactory/repository'
            credentials {
                username = "fakeuser"
                password = "fakepassword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

build.gradle module level

```
api "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$gcm_version"
api "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$gcm_version"
api "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:$gcm_version"
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.3'
```

Error:

```
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
  Required by:
      project :module1 > project :module2 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1
      project :module1 > project :module2 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1
      project :module1 > project :module2 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.1
      project :module1 > project :module2 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:15.0.1
      project :module1 > project :module2 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.1 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:15.0.1
      project :module1 > project :module2 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.1 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:15.0.1 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-clearcut:15.0.1
      project :module1 > project :module2 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.1 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:15.0.1 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-clearcut:15.0.1 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-phenotype:15.0.1

166 actionable tasks: 166 executed
   > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-base.
      > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/maven-metadata.xml.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/maven-metadata.xml'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/52.40.226.158, jcenter.bintray.com/52.11.213.218] failed: connect timed out
```

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I do no see that you have the "play-services-base" as a requirement in your build.gradle, so I guess that it is a dependency for one or more of the packages that you are pulling. My guess is that the "pom.xml" file of one of the packages you are pulling references this package as a dependency and has the JCenter URL hardcoded to the "pom.xml". You will need to find this "pom.xml" file and change the URL from JCenter to your Artifactory instance.

Comment: I checked the .pom and there is no url for dependency
```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
      <artifactId>play-services-base</artifactId>
      <version>[15.0.1,16.0.0)</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
```